# Disappearing UISearchBar on backswipe

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I'm using a `UISearchBar` in `self.navigationItem.titleView`. When I do a backswipe, this search bar disappears, and if I cancel the backswipe, it stays hidden. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it under `viewWillAppear` instead of after `viewDidLoad`. At least for the view controllers you want it to show up on.